# How to use Javascript to check whether a value of a column in a Sharepoint list is either empty or null?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have one Manager Approval form where manager can just Approve and submit it without putting their name/email. I don't want that, is there a way to add a snippet in Script editor so they can submit their form until they put their email/name. I tried using sharepoint built in feature "Require that this column contains information" but that doesn't work in these case because on my new form I hide this column.

Comment: Hi, @andy. Can you explain a bit better what the situation is? Your question sounds like its asking a user to put their name/email into fields that are hidden. If they are hidden, how are they going to fill in the information? Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't have to ask people what their email is. If they can log into SharePoint they have an email, and you should be able to fetch it.